# push elements at specific indices in ruby array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays

I have an array of arrays being returned from a db and want to make sure they are always the same length.  When they are not I want to push zeroes to make them the proper length but also maintain the integrity of the indices.

Most times it will look like

```
array = [["apple", "blueberries", "banana", "kiwi"], ["20.15", "13.50", "22.10", "10.50"], ["10", "12", "26", "34"]]
```

I'll eventually be calling `each_with_index` and will need them to match up ie. apple,20.15,10 in a table.

Every so often, one or two elements could be missing from an array and I'd like to push zeroes into their place.

```
array2 = [["apple", "blueberries", "banana", "kiwi"], ["20.15", "22.10"], ["10", "12", "26", "34"]]
```

I've tried something like

```
array2.each {|f| f.push(0) until f.length === 4}
=>[["apple", "blueberries", "banana", "kiwi"], ["20.15", "13.50", 0, 0], ["10", "12", "26", "34"]]
```

but the zeroes are going to be pushed to the end of the array - Ideally the output would be

```
=>[["apple", "blueberries", "banana", "kiwi"], ["20.15", 0, "13.50", 0], ["10", "12", "26", "34"]]
```

Comment: You should provide more info. Is there any criteria? (type, expected values lists, etc) -- As you have described, there is no (clear) way to understand what's missing. i.e. if an array has 3 items instead of 4, is there a way to decide which one is missing?

Comment: It looks inconsistent. Are you sure you want to push a number zero where other elements are strings?

Comment: Also, are the strings in the first array some sort of _headers_? If they are, can the first array (headers) have missing items?

Comment: If it comes from a DB, you should also say what gem (DB adapter) you are using. Most likely there is a way to get a `Hash` instead of an `Array` of arrays.

Comment: I was trying to break it down to what I thought was the most basic version of my problem but it looks like I went too far and didn't provide enough info.  @tompave, in your scenario I wouldn't need to know which one doesn't have 4 - any array can have missing items, they are not headers.  I appreciate the insight and I hash is the way to go.

Comment: @sawa, its ok for them to be just numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hate to break it to you, but programming is not an easy task for kids, as non-programmer adults sometimes imagine. Your case calls for creation of a separate class, perhaps a subclass of Array. Like this:

```
class GreenGrocer < Array
end
```

Now we could imagine redefining `GreenGrocer.new` public class method to make sure that each `GreenGrocer` instance has missing elements patched with zeroes, like this:

```
class GreenGrocer # reopening the class we defined earlier
  class << self
    def new array
      produce, float_array, int_array = array.reduce( &:zip ).map( &:flatten ).transpose
      super [ produce, float_array.map { |e| e or 0.0 }, int_array.map { |e| e or 0 } ]
    end

    def [] *elements; new elements end
  end
end

# so we can call

g = GreenGrocer.new( array2 )

# or

g = GreenGrocer[ *array2 ]
```

But why bother? It is enough to make a `#to_table` method that converts your incomplete data structure to a table as you require, filling the missing data points with zero in the process. So we define:

```
class LazierGreenGrocer < Array
  def to_table
    reduce( &:zip ).map( &:flatten ).map { |e| e.map { |e| e || 0 } }
  end
end

lazier_g = LazierGreenGrocer.new( array2 ) # not eager to do work upon initialization
lazier_g.to_table # does the required work as #to_table is called
```

This is how I'd go about it. Since I do not know what exact kind of table do you want to output, you may have to modify my `#to_table` method accordingly.

Comment: went with the `#to_table` method and it worked great.  Thanks!

Comment: I still don't think this solution would work, given how you have described the problem. It fills the gaps as it finds them, just like your original - not working - solution.

Comment: @topmave, the exact behavior is not important. It is easy to program any kind of behavior. What is important is that this case _envies_ an OO solution.

Answer (score 0):

Making some assumptions here:

1. You don't care if they match up (as per your sample output).
2. `array2` is always going to be size 4.
3. `array2` will only ever be missing either 1 or 2 elements.

```
    array3 = case array2.size
    when 4
      array2
    when 3
      array2 + [0]
    when 2
      array2.zip([0, 0]).flatten
    else
      raise "problem"
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `Array#insert`

```
>> a = [1, 2, 3]
=> [1, 2, 3]
>> a.insert(1, "i am new")
=> [1, "i am new", 2, 3]
```